# AutomationElement for WPF ToggleButton - have ClassName Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, ui-automation

I am using ToggleButtons in the ToolBar  and I want to get and use them in the UI Automation tests, but when I check AutomationElement.Current for these buttons, its ClassName property is Button, while I would expect ToggleButton

The xaml is not starightforward, so I mention it here :

```
<ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

for the type that's in the ItemsSource I have a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModelType}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyToolBarElementTemplate}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ThisStyleSetsWidthAndHeight}"/>
         </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

the style is defined as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}" x:Key="ThisStyleSetsWidthAndHeight"> 
    <Setter Property="styles:AttachedProperties.ContentWidth" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="styles:AttachedProperties.ContentHeight" Value="32"/>
</Style>
```

and the content template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyToolBarElementTemplate" DataType="{x:Type myViewModelType}">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="AutomationIdThatIGetOk">
        ... 
    </ToggleButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am a bit new to Automation Framework, I guess it has to do with all these templates and styles, but is there any way to get the proper AutomationPeer instance created for this ToggleButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but when I check AutomationElement.Current for these buttons, its ClassName property is Button, while I would expect ToggleButton

Your expectation is wrong because the `ToggleButtonAutomationPeer` class actually returns the `string` "Button" from its `GetClassNameCore()` method: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Automation/Peers/ToggleButtonAutomationPeer.cs,a58abe77888c16cd

So you are getting the proper instance.

Comment: I noticed, I use HelpText to identify the propper buttons now, and TogglePattern of those to do what I wanted to do